# XP Antivirus Pro malware removal

Tags: virus, malware, malware-removal

I had to remove this malware from a friends computer, and they've infected themselves again.  It's been a while since I last removed it, so can't remember the name of the program that was successful at removing it, I *think* it was a ".com" program (yeah, strange!).

Hopefully superuser can help, and then what works gets voted up instead of the piles and piles of junk commercial stuff that pops up in search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Malwarebytes booted into safe mode
Sometimes you need to rename the .exe file, if the malware is "smart"
I also have a cd-r burnt with all these malware scanners, so its read only :)
This way no matter what, the malware can't delete it (though it CAN block it from running
if it detects the name, so rename the .exe files)

If they re-infected you may want to update their computer to SP3 if not already
as well as any other updates.

Comment: Malwarebytes worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [HijackThis](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/) to remove all sorts of spyware. It is really powerfull, but also really dangerous to mess up your computer. You should first post logs so that experienced people can evaluate them.

### Using HijackThis

> To analyze your computer, start HijackThis and run a
>   scan. See the Quick Start Guide [link
>   to Quick Start, FAQs and Feedback] for
>   help in running a scan. HijackThis
>   will display a list of areas on your
>   computer that might have been changed
>   by spyware. Do not change any settings
>   if you are unsure of what to do. There
>   are many popular support forums on the
>   web that provide free technical
>   assistance by using HijackThis log
>   files to diagnose an infected
>   computer.
>
> Not an expert? Just save the
>   HijackThis report and let a friend
>   with more troubleshooting experience
>   take a look. A large community of
>   users participates in online forums,
>   where experts help interpret
>   HijackThis scan results to clean up
>   infected computers.

**P.S:**
I also liked [malware bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) to scan my computer when I was still using Windows. Luckily I made the switch to linux a long time ago and no more spyware :).

Answer (score 0):

I used this [link](http://www.xp-vista.com/spyware-removal/antivirus-xp-pro-2009-removal-antivirusxppro2009)'s manual instructions to clean the registry when I got it on my laptop a while back. Had to boot in Safe mode (F8 on startup) to delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

**To remove Antivirus XP Pro, follow these steps:**

- STEP 1: Print out instructions before we begin.
- STEP 2: Use Rkill to terminate suspicious programs.
- STEP 3: Use Malwarebytes AntiMalware to Scan for Malware and Unwanted Programs
- STEP 4: Use HitmanPro to scan your computer for badware
- STEP 5: Run Secunia PSI to find outdated and vulnerable program